# CSS Columns stacking for fluid layout?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, multiple-columns, fluid-layout

I have three columns; left, middle and right and they are in a div that is 100% width of the screen. How in a media query, when the screen size is reduced, can I get the middle column to stay on the top, the left column to go underneath and then the right column to go underneath that? I've attached a CodePen as well as displaying the HTML and CSS below: https://codepen.io/Macast/pen/jZworE . Any help will be greatly appreciated! I have no idea how to go about this.

This is what I'm looking for:
[image]

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="columnContainer">
    <div class="leftColumn" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <h2>Left Column</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="middleColumn" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <h2>Middle Column</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="rightColumn" style="background-color:#ccc;">
      <h2>Right Column</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.columnContainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.leftColumn {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.middleColumn {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.rightColumn {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.columnContainer:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Media Query */
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    /* Column Stacking Here */
}
```

Comment: Use flexbox? [This little game](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) will help you learn to create the wanted result above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex` + `order`;

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.columnContainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.leftColumn {
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.middleColumn {
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.rightColumn {
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Media Query */
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* Column Stacking Here */

  .columnContainer {
      flex-direction: column;
  }

  .leftColumn {
      order: 2;
  }

  .middleColumn {
      order: 1;
  }

  .rightColumn {
      order: 3;
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="columnContainer">
    <div class="leftColumn" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <h2>Left Column</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="middleColumn" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <h2>Middle Column</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="rightColumn" style="background-color:#ccc;">
      <h2>Right Column</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I've never used flex before. Excellent answer. I can see this being very useful! I added width: 100%; to each of the columns in the media query so it fills the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Media Query */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .leftColumn, .middleColumn, .rightColumn {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
}
```